# iOS Mixing audio, Audio Toolbox vs Audio Units

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, audio-recording

I've been searching for a while and can't come to a good conclusion.

I am trying to create an app that can "record" beats that a user makes on a 4x4 button array.  Each button has a sound tied to it and after they hit record, I want to mix the audio that gets played and save it to a file so they can listen to it and play over it later.

What makes this even trickier is that there will be a metronome playing and I do not want to mix the metronome sound into the audio that is getting saved.

From what I have found, the only way to go is Audio Units for these features, but I am reluctant to since it seems a little overkill and somewhat complicated to learn.  Can Audio Toolbox make this any easier?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In generally, using a AudioToolBox easily implements.

more information, see below sample code. it's a lot of help.

[MixerHost](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MixerHost/Introduction/Intro.html)

Comment: Thanks, so it looks like Audio Units.